# pls help me to understand

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange post: [why god is like to provide a way to lie?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79072/why-god-is-like-to-provide-a-way-to-lie)

Comment: Hi John, questions on this site should *start from a text*. So there are two problems: 1) It does not clearly show which text it is about. 2) It does not ask a clear question. I would suggest editing your question so that it is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: The best thing to do is to go and find the Bible passage you are interested in, and read it carefully from beginning to end before writing your question. Perhaps you are thinking about [Genesis 27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2027&version=GNT), but you will read that God does not tell the people to do any of these things - they make the decisions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> pls help me to understand

There are multiple reasons why your post got closed. Yesterday I posted a comment there, but I see it has been removed.

The question itself ("*why god is like to provide a way to lie?*") is unintelligible even after reading the description and comments. If this is just a matter of proficiency in English, feel free to formulate your question *also* in a language with which you feel comfortable (and therefore proficient). Many contributors understand multiple languages, which increases the chances of us making sense of what you are asking.

The comments reflect that (1) the post required others to do guess work, and (2) you were confusing the biblical passage at issue. These two factors tend to frustrate any efforts because in Hermeneutics the context and subtleties very often are decisive. The requirement about providing a specific Bible reference is for purposes of setting up a common ground, or starting point, and thus preempt misunderstandings of the sort "*oh, that's not what I was asking about*". Making sure that we are all "on the same page" (pun intended) is important.

The description contains statements that seem to be truncated.

Also your subsequent [edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/revisions/79072/2) adds confusion. The edit states that "*the question is about birthright*" whereas the title refers only to the god and lying. The presumption that "*god like[s] to provide a way to lie*" seems unrelated to matters of birthright, which is why you should outline the link between these two.